# Swiperjs fade transition doesn't crossfade properly, instead adds white cross transition effect

Tags: swiper.js

I have a problem with Swiperjs, that I'm trying to make the crossfade, but it doesn't crossfade like it should, but between showing the two images it adds approximately 20% white overlay between the two images.

Hard to describe, but as if it would first fade the image to 20% white overlay, so the image brightens a bit and then it fades to the next image. So maybe it's not obvious, but still not the same as

JS:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    lazy: true,
    loop: true,
    speed: 2000,
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEffect: {
      crossFade: true
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  })
```

Just standard Swiper JS, nothing fancy here which would change how the animation behaves. HTML exactly the same as on their page, not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the same thing.I try to add "animation" function below the `transition(duration)` function.But error was throw said "animation was not a function".I don't know why I can't add my own function in the javascript source file `swiper-bundle.js`.And if modify the `transition(duration)` function directly it dosen't work either.Maybe I need read the source file deeply.